# issue with "using namespace std;"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, namespaces

I have a source code file in C++. Here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class myPoint
{
public:
    double x;
    double y;
    myPoint() {x=y=0;}
};

double distance(myPoint A, myPoint B)
{
    return (A.x - B.x);
}

int main()
{
    myPoint A, B;
    A.x=5; A.y=5;
    B.x=3; B.y=2;
    cout << distance(A, B) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And my compiler (Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2012) gives me the following error:

> ...
>   
>   1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(364): error C2039: 'iterator_category' : is not a member of 'myPoint'
>   
>   1>          d:...\source.cpp(5) : see declaration of 'myPoint'
>   
>   ...

When I removed `using namespace std;` 
and changed `cout << distance(A, B) << endl;` to 
`std::cout << distance(A, B) << std::endl;`
my program worked.

Why does the first version give me an error? What is the mistake?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: There's a reason that the standard library puts its names in the namespace `std`. Blowing away the namespace is not a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a *conflict* with `std::distance`

Answer (score 4):

> Why I cannot use 1st version of the source code? Where

Because you inadvertently pulled in a name from the `std` namespace (`std::distance`) that is the same as a name of something else you defined (`distance`). This gives you a conflict.

> Where is the mistake?

The fundamental mistake is to say `using namespace std;`, especially if you don't know every single name in the standard library, past *and* future.

It would also make sense to define your own names inside your own namespace.

```
namespace mystuff {
  class Point { ... };
  double distance(const Point& A, const Point& B);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a `std::distance` in standard library and it become visible because of `using namespace std;` and it seems that for some reason it was picked instead of your version.

Do not use `using namespace std;`. And if you insist, do not use names which sounds like common english words, because they are likely to clash with library names.